# Enabling ANSI Color support in Windows console with custom screen buffer (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, ansi-escape

I'm trying to enable ANSI color support for created console screen buffer via `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()`.

```c
hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);

DWORD dwMode = 0;
GetConsoleMode(hConsole, &dwMode);
dwMode |= ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;
SetConsoleMode(hConsole, dwMode);

dwMode = 0;
GetConsoleMode(hConsole, &dwMode);
dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
SetConsoleMode(hConsole, dwMode);

SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
```

It seems like SetConsoleMode() isn't doing anything, I can write it to buffer as I intended, but if I try to write any ANSI Escape codes, it looks like this

[image: ansii]

If I'm not in buffer created by `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()`, ANSI Escape codes are working as expected.

EDIT: I'm on Windows 10, 19041.388; C++14, MinGW-64 compiler

Comment: Try adding ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT.

Comment: I vaguely recall `SetConsoleMode` and `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`.  Assuming you are on current Windows 10.

Comment: Tried adding `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT`, problem persists.

Comment: Did you try what @Eljay suggested? `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` "_When writing with `WriteFile` or `WriteConsole`, characters are parsed for VT100 and similar control character sequences that control cursor movement, color/font mode, and other operations that can also be performed via the existing Console APIs. For more information, see Console Virtual Terminal Sequences._"

Comment: A small question, you are trying to write with different colors in the console app is that true?

Comment: Tried putting it before `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW()`, still problem persists, nothing changed. Seems like, it isn't going through VT100 parser? @TedLyngmo

Comment: @aliberro Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
void Color(int color=0x07)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color);
}
int main()
{
    Color(0x0A/*Black bg green Fg*/);
    std::cout << "Hello";
    Color();
    std::cout << ",";
    Color(0xAC/*Green bg red Fg*/);
     std::cout << "World";
    Color(/*Black bg white Fg*/);
}
```

For more information about the colors:

Color attributes are specified by TWO hex digits -- the first
corresponds to the background; the second the foreground.  Each digit
can be any of the following values:

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

Comment: Interestingly, it isn't changing text color while writing with `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW()`. (used `SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole /* My buffer */, 0x0C);`)

Comment: @Mayuna yes this would change the color before writing. Right after you call this function, everything that is written to the console would be in that color, it's a nice hack

Answer (score 1):

> Virtual terminal sequences are control character sequences that can
> control cursor movement, color/font mode, and other operations when
> written to the output stream. Sequences may also be received on the
> input stream in response to an output stream query information
> sequence or as an encoding of user input when the appropriate mode is
> set.
>
> You can use [GetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode) and [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) functions to configure
> this behavior.

From [ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode#parameters), we can use `WriteFile` or `WriteConsole` to achieve.

Some code:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

HANDLE hConsole_c = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole_c);
DWORD dwMode = 0;
GetConsoleMode(hConsole_c, &dwMode);
dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
SetConsoleMode(hConsole_c, dwMode);

const char* str = "\x1b[31mThis text has restored the foreground color only.\r\n";
DWORD len = strlen(str);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

WriteConsole(hConsole_c, str, len, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```

Debug:

[image]